# Fixtures names in cakePHP (test)

Tags: unit-testing, postgresql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, fixtures

i keep fixtures in:  app/test/fixture/ directory

and for e.x.
app/test/fixture/UserRoleHistoryFixture.php looks this way

```
<?php

 class UserRoleHistoryFixture extends CakeTestFixture {
    public $import = array('model' => 'UserRoleHistory', 'records' => false, 'connection' => 'test');
}
```

app/Test/Fixture/UserFixture.php looks this way

```
 class UserFixture extends CakeTestFixture {
    public $import = array('model' => 'User', 'records' => true, 'connection' => 'test');
}
```

All fixtures looks this (only difference is somtimes records are set true)
Then in my UserTest.php(model) im using its this way:

```
class UserTest extends CakeTestCase {
public $fixtures = array('app.user', 'app.user_role','app.session', 'app.users_activity', 'app.user_role_history'
    );
 public $autoFixtures = false;
 public function setUp() {
    parent::setUp();


    $this->loadFixtures('User','UserRoleHistory','Session','UserRole','UsersActivity');
));
```

And what i get while trying to do some test i PDO error and stack trace , mayby i called sth wrong way ? Guess that it's problem with how i make my fixture but dont know ..
Thanks for ideas !

Edit:
my problem changed a little, there is error and stack trace:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[23503]: Foreign key violation: 7 BŁĄD: modyfikacja lub usunięcie     na tabeli "users" narusza klucz obcy "user_role_history_user_id" tabeli "user_role_history"      DETAIL: Klucz (id)=(26381) ma wciąż odwołanie w tabeli "user_role_history".
Test case: UserTest(testUserNameExists)
Stack trace:
C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\EnterpriseDB-    ApachePHP\apache\www\soig\www\konkursy2.0\lib\Cake\Model\Datasource\DboSource.php : 436
C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\EnterpriseDB-ApachePHP\apache\www\soig\www\konkursy2.0\lib\Cake\Model\Datasource\DboSource.php : 403
C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\EnterpriseDB-ApachePHP\apache\www\soig\www\konkursy2.0\lib\Cake\Model\Datasource\Database\Postgres.php : 309
C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\EnterpriseDB-ApachePHP\apache\www\soig\www\konkursy2.0\lib\Cake\TestSuite\Fixture\CakeTestFixture.php : 232
C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\EnterpriseDB-ApachePHP\apache\www\soig\www\konkursy2.0\lib\Cake\TestSuite\Fixture\CakeFixtureManager.php : 236
C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\EnterpriseDB-ApachePHP\apache\www\soig\www\konkursy2.0\lib\Cake\TestSuite\CakeTestCase.php : 191
C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\EnterpriseDB-ApachePHP\apache\www\soig\www\konkursy2.0\app\Test\Case\Model\UserTest.php : 16
C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\EnterpriseDB-ApachePHP\apache\www\soig\www\konkursy2.0\vendors\PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase.php : 801
C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\EnterpriseDB-ApachePHP\apache\www\soig\www\konkursy2.0\app\webroot\test.php : 92
```

Also what i got is

```
 Fatal Error (256): [PDOException] You cannot serialize or unserialize PDOStatement  instances
 #0 [internal function]: PDOStatement->__sleep()
 etc ;/
```

i see the first problem is about foregin key, and that when test is used to delete table users there is foregin key violation but is it problem about how the database is created ?

Comment: make sure you have your casing right! /Test/Fixture/ for example for folder names. it might work on windows due to CI but not on other systems then.

Comment: i have a folder structure like this :
Test/ containing those 3:
  Case/  Fixture/  Group/
  Case extends to : Behaviour/ Component/ Controller/ Helper/ Model/ AllTest.php
And i'm working on windows 7

Comment: A little more information relating to the error could assist a great deal. Even if it's a copy paste of the output. Sound's like it's potentially an issue with the way you've created a table. Having multiple foreign_key's may cause such an error.

Potentially use cake bake to create your fixtures/cases with the basics and add/adjust what you need from there.

Comment: Tom and how to use cake bake to create fixtures ? I'm pretty new in testing so don't know such a things yet.

Comment: Using google translate, the error says `Foreign key violation: 7 ERROR: modify or delete the table "users" violates foreign key constraint "user_role_history_user_id" table "user_role_history" DETAIL: Key (id) = (26381) is still referenced in the table "user_role_history".`

Comment: i know it and as i guess i have to change in user_role_history in database ON DELETE NO ACTION  to CASCADE, will try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You importing from 'test' datasource, remove that in your fixtures. it pull from default, or specify another to pull from if you like. It will create in 'test' instead of importing from it

Comment: u mean this:'connection' => 'test' ? but does it matters when my test database is exacly te same as my default ? because my test database is just local copy of the real one

Comment: You test db should be empty, the testsuite will build the tables based off the fixtures and drop them after running tests